# Where does PHP's error log reside in XAMPP?

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I've been using XAMPP for Windows.

Where does PHP's error log reside in XAMPP?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

`\xampp\apache\logs\error.log`, where `xampp` is your installation folder.
If you haven't changed the `error_log` setting in PHP (check with `phpinfo()`), it will be logged to the Apache log.

Comment: This path does not exist in xampp for Linux (Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: For me (macOS), the error log path lives inside the vm (which took me an embarassingly long time to realise). I only know how to access via the xampp control panel terminal, with a path of: `/opt/lampp/logs/php_error_log`

Comment: The answer is wrong or icomplete in a way that the ApacheFriends did not think of creating the `logs` folder, shame on them.  Create a folder `logs` under `C:\xampp\php`

Answer (score 64):

I found it in: 
`\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log`

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  In the newer version of XAMPP, this is the correct directory.

Comment: Correct, the question should be edited to include a XAMPP version to make the current accepted answer true too...

Comment: On my version of XAMPP the root folder is lampp instead of xampp. Otherwise the location is the same.

Answer (score 19):

You can also open the XAMPP control panel and click on the button <kbd>Logs</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: Nice arrow :D @Black

Comment: If I click this, the file is not found. How can I set the path so it will find the log file?

Answer (score 15):

`\xampp\php\logs` did not exist at all for me - for whatever reason.

I simply had to create a folder in `\xampp\php\` called `logs` and then the `php_error_log` file was created and written to.

Comment: Worked like a charm

Comment: Was the case for me, too. Seems like newer installations of XAMPP are bizarrely missing this folder for some reason.

Answer (score 12):

For Mac users, XAMPP version 1.7.3:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/logs/error_log
```

Comment: In the newer version, it was just /Applications/XAMPP/logs for me.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone searching for the PHP log file in XAMPP for Ubuntu, it is:

```
/opt/lampp/logs/php_error_log
```

Most probably it will be having a big size (mine was about 350 MBs) and it slowed down my text editor when I opened the file. If you do not care about all the previous logs you can empty the file easily by simply going to the terminal and then writing these three lines one by one:

```
sudo su 
cd /opt/lampp/logs/
> php_error_log
```

And newer logs will be easy and fast to open now. The angle bracket empties the file (Works with `bash` only, doesn't work on zsh).

Comment: What is executing `php_error_log` supposed to do/accomplish? Ask for some application to open the file? Or is the intent different? Can you elaborate? Preferably by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31500869/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: Why did you remove the angle bracket? You are editing other people's answer and breaking them without understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Look in your configuration file and search for the error_log setting. Or use phpinfo() to find this setting.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply check your log path from [phpMyAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin).

Run this:

> **http://localhost/dashboard/**

Now click *PHPInfo* (top right corner) or you can simply open this URL in your browser:

> **http://localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php**

Now search for ***"error_log"***(without quotes). You will get the log path.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the XAMPP PHP log file path is in */xampp_installation_folder/php/logs/php_error_log*, but I noticed that sometimes it would not be generated automatically. Maybe it could be a Windows account write permission problem? I am not sure, but I created the logs folder and *php_error_log* file manually and then PHP logs were logged in it finally.

Answer (score 1):

*\xampp\apache\logs\error.log* is the default location of error logs in PHP.

Comment: No. It could also be `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. It may not even be true for XAMPP. On what system was this observed? Windows?

Answer (score 1):

As said in previous answers, you can find the PHP error log in Windows. In `C:\xampp\apache\logs\error.log`. You can easily display the last logs by `tail -f .\error.log`.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac users, it can be found in:

/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/logs/php_error_log

Answer (score 1):

In the current version I've just installed (8.0.11) the installer "forgets" to create the folder `C:\xamppp\php\logs`, perhaps by design but that is ApacheFriends for you. After creating the folder and restarting Apache the folder will be populated with a `php_error_log` file. No, not a php_error.log but php_error_log, becouse they are your friends.

### Follow

### Terminal

To keep seeing the last entry (much like *nix sh `tail -f`) use the following command:

```
Get-Content c:\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log -Wait
```

This will keep reading the file and display the last entries. Quite handy if you are debugging.

### Code

You might be using vscode so why not have the errors right at you finger tips. Create a file `.vscode\tasks.json`

```
{ 
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558 
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format 
  "version": "2.0.0", 
  "tasks": [ 
    { 
      "label": "Monitor php errors", 
      "type": "shell", 
      "command": "Get-Content -Wait c:\\xampp\\php\\logs\\php_error_log", 
      "runOptions": { 
        "runOn": "folderOpen" 
      } 
    } 
  ]
```

and allow it to run on start. Make sure you work on a folder, not single files, but you were doing that already, weren't you?

Answer (score 0):

For my issue, I had to zero out the log:

`sudo bash -c ' > /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/logs/php_error_log '`