# JSON not working in php script

Tags: php, json

I'm not getting the json_encode to work in my php file. Like for instance, I tried this example I got from php.net

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

But nothing works. If i remove the echo statement, then my php works, which means php isn't recognizing the json_encode code.

I'm using PHP 5.4.16. To sum it up, I'm using xampp 1.8.2.

Help please?

Comment: What exactly is happening when you say "nothing works"? Are you getting an error, or no output?

Comment: Where is this PHP block in your page ? Is that the whole page ?

Comment: Try using `json_last_error()` to see what error you're getting. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: @StephenTG no output.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://codepad.org/sq1LmgZb. If you have a problem, you should describe it properly. Especially you have to provide code that *reproduces* the problem.

Comment: Are you getting anything if you do `print_r($arr)` ?

Comment: @KAy what are you seeing when you remove the json_encode call?

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);` to the top of your file.

Comment: @dystroy its at the end. The rest of the code works normally, but just can't use the json code at all.

Comment: What does it mean, "at the end" ? How is it supposed to be rendered ?

Comment: You should check PHP/Apache log files. Maybe something is wrong with your configuration. Like missing some essential element. You would have the answer in the logs.

Comment: @Thibault thanks for the suggestion. This is what it says in the log:
Can't use function return value in write context

Comment: Is your script used like this as standalone ? Is it complete ? Is it called by another script like eval or something ?

Comment: standalone. I just used that as a test to see if JSON is working. After that statement i have something like echo" alert('works');"; to make sure it works but the message never alerts unless I remove the json_encode statement

Comment: @Kay: `Can't use function return value in write context`.  That means you have `isset(func())` or `empty(func())`; you can't do that.  They only work on variables.

Comment: well it's a multidimensional array i'm trying to send

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there could be a fatal error somewhere else in your script. Make sure `display_errors` is set to `On` in php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

This question can not be answered without more debug beeing provided.

As in the comments suggested, use these lines before everything to (try to) enable error reporting:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', true);
// Json
echo json_last_error();
```

Use `phpinfo();` to obtain information about PHP Version and JSON support.

This snippet will tell you if the json function is available:

```
<?php
if (!function_exists('json_encode')) {
    echo 'PHP not compiled with json support', PHP_EOL;
}
```

Last but not least, check errors logs

```
/var/log/httpd*
/var/log/nginx*
/var/log/php-fpm*
/var/log/apache*
.... (linux)
```

From [Where does PHP's error log reside in XAMPP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719549/where-does-phps-error-log-reside-in-xampp)

```
\xampp\apache\logs\error.log
```

or

```
\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log
```

Comment: `text/pain`.  That made me laugh :)

Comment: Good advice except for the header() function. A) script might have already echoed something to output buffer causing more errors/confusion, B) many configurations use HTML formatted error messages, B) no real point in end