# XAMPP gives me a blank page?

Tags: xampp

I've been using XAMPP ever since, I get this problem. Whenever I go to my page "127.0.0.1/advancedtempl" It doesn't give me an error, Just a blank soulless page, I'm not sure what's going on, I've tried putting index.php and trying other pages but no avail. What do I do?

EDIT:

This is my error logs:

```
[Thu Aug 15 22:25:23.186600 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7224:tid 344] AH00430: Parent: Child process 2036 exited successfully.
[Thu Aug 15 22:25:37.607600 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 6540:tid 344] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Aug 15 22:25:38.359600 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 6540:tid 344] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Aug 15 22:25:38.498600 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6540:tid 344] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Aug 15 22:25:38.498600 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6540:tid 344] AH00456: Server built: Feb 23 2013 13:07:34
[Thu Aug 15 22:25:38.498600 2013] [core:notice] [pid 6540:tid 344] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Thu Aug 15 22:25:38.502600 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6540:tid 344] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5868
[Thu Aug 15 22:25:39.881600 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 5868:tid 244] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Aug 15 22:25:40.868600 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 5868:tid 244] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Aug 15 22:25:41.005600 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5868:tid 244] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Comment: Look in the [error logs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719549/where-does-phps-error-log-reside-in-xampp).

Comment: Now i'm getting access denied on my phpmyadmin:  Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed. #1130 - Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server