# phpMyAdmin - Error in xampp phpmyadmin for windows XP

Tags: php, xampp

I have installed XAMPP. In XAMPP Control Panel Apache and MySQL running.

When i run PHPMyAdmin in localhost, it shows error like this (please see this link): https://i.stack.imgur.com/osRcv.jpg

Can anyone tell me, how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What your server log says?

Comment: @panther:May i know where is locate server log?

Comment: why don't you try restarting your PC..

Comment: @FahadAjmal: I already restrated..

Comment: @saina: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719549/where-does-phps-error-log-reside-in-xampp

Comment: @panther: In error.log lots of contents here. How to show you?

Comment: Please check your XAMPP/PHP version. 5.5 is not supported in XP.. 

XAMPP 1.8.2 (with PHP 5.4): Windows 2003, 2008, 2012, XP, Vista, 7, 8 XAMPP 1.8.3 (with PHP 5.5): (Important: XP or 2003 not supported) 2008, 2012, Vista, 7, 8.

Comment: @saina: in the error log there will be a lot of warning (I suppose), you are looking for errors. Each line has a datetime, so look for today errors only.

Comment: @panther: please see this link : http://imgur.com/1Zmdxnb

Comment: @FahadAjmal: I installed XAMPP1.8.2(with PHP 5.4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check cookie is enabled ?
Enable cookie
in chrome go to this link

chrome://settings/content#cookie

and select first option under cookie

Comment: @wisdomLabs: I followed your answer, but nothing seems to be happen.

Comment: @wisdomlabs: now it displays 'access denied'.

Comment: may be your php session is not geeting saved on ur pc coz of access permission 
check php.ini for ,,
cookie.save_path
session.save_path ,,in xamp console there is a direct link to get to php.ini

Comment: @WisdomLabs: now reinstalled. so pleasae see this link http://imgur.com/6jR2IMu. now displays token mismatch.