# Why do I get an internal server error from my SQL query?

Tags: php

I am attempting to retrieve some data from my database, I appear to be able to connect to the database as I do not get an error message after the connection is tested. But when I attempt to run a select query, it causes an internal error.

If I take the FROM part away from the query, the page loads with no data. If I add the FROM part back in, with the table to be selected from, the internal error occurs.

The code is below:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("50.62.209.87:3306","myusername","mypassword",
"FiveExtras");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

     $query = "SELECT `EventVenue`,`EventDate`,`EventTime`,
     `EventPostCode` FROM `event`";

  $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);


$row = $result;

echo $row;
```

Comment: Check out your error_log

Comment: I dont know what I am looking for though

Comment: If you are using XAMPP have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719549/where-does-phps-error-log-reside-in-xampp)

Comment: No using XAMPP, will have a lok at it anyway

Answer (score 1):

did you change your htacess? Changes to .htacess often cause internal server error. or your host **ip is bad(try no-ip.com, they give free subdomains for your ip's)**

---

**i checked it with removed port it worked(well...not connecting but no error about host), so maybe it's something to do with port**

---

if error 500 remains try get support ticket or email webmaster or get another hosting provider

---

> why would you say no error?

here we go:

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given
in /home/u451361813/public_html/test.php on line 13
```

and

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user
'myusername'@'185.28.20.221' (using password: YES) in /home/u451361813
/public_html/test.php on line 3
Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 
'myusername'@'185.28.20.221' (using password: YES)
```

1st one is for no information returned second for no password

Comment: OK tahnsk, I took the host address from the databse section on my godadddy management page so i thought it would be ok

Comment: I hope theOP didn't include the ACTUAL ID/pwd to a live database.

Comment: No,  I used 'myusername' and 'mypassword' to show that I had no left the fields blank

Comment: I took the database select out to see if the database connection was ok so thas probably why you could see it without error. I have put the database select back in now, so the error is back

Comment: did you try your ip and/or port?

Comment: I dont have a test.php file anymore, so I am not sure why that is showing up

Comment: I have tried the ip with the socket, how do I tryy the port?

Comment: that from my test page

Comment: if you can, try to remove :3306 at the end of your ip and see what happens

Comment: but surly you would need my login details to test it?

Comment: you can create new blank db for me to test it

Comment: also if you're on shared hosting theres email ...@...... try emailing them or getting a ticked

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your connection:

```
$db_conn = mysqli_connect("$host", "$dbuser", "$dbpass") or die("Unable to connect to the database");
mysql_select_db("$dbase", $db_conn) or die("Unable to select the database");

$query = mysqli_query("SELECT `EventVenue`,`EventDate`,`EventTime`,
 `EventPostCode` FROM `event`");
```

And why `$result = $row` ?

EDIT: For a better query , use `"SELECT * ... "`

Comment: I have changed my code to yours. The code for connecting seems to work, but the database select causes internal error

Comment: it gives 500 internal error, I tto screen print but cant find a way to show you.

Comment: note a small typo, it should be `mysqli_select_db'.

Comment: Using `SELECT * ...` doesn't make it a better query. Select only the fields you need.