# wordpress installation taking too long

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, execution-time

I don't have much to explain about the issue as I am absolutely new to wordpress. I am installing wordpress on my local machine by following very general steps of installation. I have to fill the information regarding my database name, server user name, password and one more field of table prefix for creating wp-config.php file. As I submit this form the page get too long to process, but the required file is not created. Anybody can help?

Comment: There is not that much we can actually help you with without knowing more about your system. What local web server are you using (MAMP, WAMP, XAMPP etc?). What version of PHP? Do you have a MySQL  server running and is the port / username / pw correct? Respond by editing your question - not by commenting.

Comment: I am using XAMPP. The php version is 5.6.3. Yes the MySQL server is running and username, password are also correct(I am using default values for MySQL)

Comment: Have you tried checking the error log? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719549/where-does-phps-error-log-reside-in-xampp

Comment: no, I didn't check it. Can you please tell me from where I can check it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719549/where-does-phps-error-log-reside-in-xampp

Comment: No there is no error in the error log file

Answer (score 0):

Windows folder permission could be the problem to edit wp-config.php file.

Be sure that your XAMPP user have permissions to edit file under your localhost directory (Generally directory is : C:\xammp\www). You can check these permissions with right clicking yo your localhost directory -> properties -> security tab.

I think giving full permission this folder and sub folders is not a bad idea unless if you are at development stage of your project.

Answer (score 0):

A better alternative to usually to create the configuration file yourself by copying `wp-config-sample.php` to `wp-config.php` and writing in the correct values for the database etc.

This way you don't need to mess with the file permissions in your wordpress root folder (making it writable can be a security hazard which must be fixed later).

When you then run Wordpress the first time it will populate the database with tables.

Comment: On a side note, you may want to check your error reporting settings in XAMPP. Check the documentation for instructions.