# php variable to javascript with json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I know this topic was already discussed a few times but I can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong.

What I'm trying to do:
The user types in a number and by clicking on the button creates a table with that number of columns.

Heres the php:

```
<?php
$twig = require_once('bootstrap.php');
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password =  '';
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=mydb", $username, $password);

echo $twig->render('index.html', array());

$numOfRows = 1;

if(isset($_POST['button'])){
    $numOfRows = $_POST['num_input'];
}
```

html/javascript:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function insertRows(){
    var numOfRows = <?php echo json_encode($numOfRows) ?>;
    var out = "<table><tr><th>test</th>";

    for (i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++){
        out += "<th>test</th>";
    }

    out += "</tr></table>";
    document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <textarea id="num_input" name ="num_input"></textarea>
  <button type="button"  name="button" onclick="insertRows()"> Go </button>
</form>

<p id="table"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Theres no error or anything since I'm not using a IDE, just doing it in vim but the error is that is just doesn't happen. If i change "numOfRows" in the for loop to a number it works, so I'm pretty sure the json_encode is the problem.

Thanks!

EDIT:
Just to test it, I used a string variable `$str = "test";` the php file, and instead of using the for loop, I just edited javascript to

```
var str = <?php echo json_encode($str); ?>;
alert(str);
```

and  I also tried

```
var str = <?php echo $str; ?>;
alert(str);
```

but nothing works.

Comment: That's the js var numOfRows not the php one. Why would I have to use $ in javascript variable?

Comment: why are you using json ?

Comment: Why is `numOfRows` actually a count of the number of columns?

Comment: devlin carnate: why not, what else would be good to use? I'm new to php and I'm just playing around, I'm happy to try out something else :)

Comment: What do you see when you do `View Source`?

Comment: @mcCat If you want to send a comment to someone, you have to put @ before their name.

Answer (score 4):

`json_encode` is not necessary in this case.

Simply replace

```
var numOfRows = <?php echo json_encode($numOfRows); ?>;
```

with

```
var numOfRows = <?php echo (int)$numOfRows; ?>;
```

Comment: Added semicolons inside PHP part. Maybe it will help.

Comment: If that also doesn't work, then there's nothing wrong with `json_encode()`. The problem is that `$numOfRows` isn't defined when that line of code runs. `$numOfRows` is defined in your first code block, but how are the two code blocks connected to each other? Setting it in one place doesn't magically make it work elsewhere.#

Answer (score 0):

Edit: You are missing a ; on the

```
<?php echo json_encode($numOfRows) ?>
```

Should be

```
<?php echo json_encode($numOfRows);?>
```

And in these cases, if would be good to check the server log, this will automaticly make you better at finding these mistakes yourself.

---

You are mixing up ints and strings. The database will in PHP always return strings and the way you are using the variable as an int in a for loop.

The following change i believe would achieve the right result.

```
$numOfRows = intval($_POST['num_input']);
```

Where you use PHP's conversion to integer function there is at a global level.

Comment: But `i < numOfRows` will convert `numOfRows` to an integer before comparing, so the result should be the same.

Comment: Tried it but unfortunately it didn't help :/

Comment: Updated my post, got that version working in phpfiddle without the javascript thou

Comment: ; at the end doesn't help either.

Comment: @Martin Henriksen how do I do that? :) Do you mean debugging in developer tools?

Comment: What php version do you have installed and what server are you running it on?

Comment: @Martin Heriksen 5.6.12 and I'm using xampp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719549/where-does-phps-error-log-reside-in-xampp

Answer (score -1):

You did not forget any $.  JS does not need $ for variables.

As far as your json_encode is concerned, if you are just passing an integer from PHP to JS, there is no need to json_encode.  Just pass the variable to JS as `<?=$numOfRows?>` in the JS source.

Comment: Don't assume they have short-tags enabled.

Comment: WIth PHP 5.4+ the `<?=` *(echo shorthand)* is available without having short tags enabled ... granted you're then assuming they've either got short tags enabled *or* 5.4+ : http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php