# My PHP Code doesn't get executed

Tags: php, html, mysql, xampp

Link to my project:
http://www.mediafire.com/download/1ebozib6qdq2obd/Delivery4All.rar

Basically when i try to open displaymenus.php my php code doesn't get executed but my html code gets

I have xampp for windows but i don't think the problem is in the xampp but in my code

Code for displaymenus.php:

```
<a href="displayshops.php" class="button">hello</a>
<?php
require 'controllers/menucontroller.php';
$menuController = new menucontroller();
if(!empty($_POST['types']))
{
    $menuTables = $menuController->createmenutables($_POST['types']);
}else{

  $menuTables = $menuController->createmenutables('^');
}
$content = $menuController->createtypedropdown() . $menuTables;
    $title = 'Deliver4All';
    include_once 'template.php';
    ?>
```

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? Do you have display_errors on?

Comment: No I havent checked neither i have display_errors on

Comment: where is the error log on windows?

Comment: Error logs http://stackoverflow.com/a/3719566/5509627

Comment: Please help i need to get this project done in a week

Comment: Thats my [error log:](http://www.mediafire.com/download/c4da4mdrjj51hu2/error+log.txt)