# jquery did not send post data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

iam trying to control a dropdown select with previous dropdown select.
the content of second dropdown select depend on what we select from first dropdown select.
iam using ajax to call another php script to change the content of second dropdown select

my code is

```
<div class="qst"><h4>PILIHAN 1</h4></div>
<div>
    <select id="ptn1" class="font" name="ptn1" style="width: 200px;">
         <?php echo $opt_ptn; ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <select id="prodi1" name="prodi1" class="font">
         <option value="">-Pilih Kota Terlebih Dulu-</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

and the jquery file is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ptn1').on('change', function(){
        var ptn1_ID = $(this).val();
        if(ptn1_ID){
            $.ajax({
               type:'POST',
               url:'queryptn.php',
               data:'ptn1='+ptn1_ID,
               success:function(html){
                   $('#prodi1').html(html);
               }
           }); 
       }else{
           $('#prodi1').html('<option value="">-Pilih Terlebih  Dulu-</option>');
       }
    }); 
});
```

and my php script is

```
<?php
//Include database configuration file
include "include/dbconnect.inc"; 

if(isset($_POST["ptn1"]) && !empty($_POST["ptn1"])){
    $kodeptn = $_POST["ptn1"];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM t_dataprodi WHERE c_kodeptn = '$kodeptn'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($rowCount > 0) {
        echo '<option value="">-Pilih Prodi-</option>';
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<option value='".$row['c_kodeprodi']."'>".$row['c_namaprodi']."</option>";
        }
    } else {
        echo '<option value="">'.$kodeptn.'</option>';        
    }
}
?>
```

please tell where is my mistake, the code isn't working

Thanks

Comment: "isn't working" isn't a clear enough explanation of the problem. Are you getting an error in the Javascript console? Is there an error in the PHP log?

Comment: You don't need to test `isset` and `!empty`, because `empty` automatically performs an `isset` check.

Comment: What is the content of "$opt_ptn"?

Comment: @Barmar where can i find error log? iam using localhost (XAMMP)

Comment: @RtmEff I found this by googling "php error log xampp". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719549/where-does-phps-error-log-reside-in-xampp Why couldn't you do that yourself?