# The localhost page isn’t working in xcart 4.6.7Gold

Tags: php, mysql

I have downloaded live (live site-currently working) x-cart 4.6.7 Gold files from cpanel to localhost

Provided permission and i have changed config file as per localhost information for db credentials and path.

But I am unable to open the link as per live link in localhost

I am getting this error

> The localhost page isn’t working.localhost is currently unable to
>   handle this request.500

Comment: Firstly check your local server is either running or not. According to W3 protocol, 500 Error is for internal server error. Check here https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: Yes Ananda. Since other php file is working fine, local server is working. This x-cart folder only is not working

Comment: x-cart 4.6.7 have some server requirements, did your local server accepts all the requirements? Please check or review the documentation. I think your x-cart is not supported by your local server, that means you are using a un-matching version. Please check here for requirements. https://help.x-cart.com/index.php?title=X-Cart:Server_Requirements_(X-Cart_4.5,_4.6,_4.7)

Comment: I have checked with requirement, some requirement is satisfied and i have added requirement which is not satisfied. But x-cart 5 working fine. I don't know why this "x-cart 4.6.7" version not working.

Comment: Any error checking code or script is available to find what  the error is encountered in that?

Comment: As far as I can infer that No. Buy not sure. But I can imagine that the problem is due to PHP version. Are you using Xamp server on Windows PC?

Comment: No, I am using PHP7 xampp server in linux ubuntu

Comment: Yes. So problem is there, I think. x-Cart-4.6.7 is supported by PHP 5.3~5.6 possibly. Please check. `PHP7 is recommended for X-Cart versions 4.7.6 and later for better performance`.

Comment: In this link "https://help.x-cart.com/index.php?title=X-Cart:Server_Requirements_(X-Cart_4.5,_4.6,_4.7)" it is mentioned as "X-Cart 4.5.3-4.6.6: PHP version 5.2.0 or later is required.
X-Cart 4.7.0 and later: PHP version 5.3.0 or later is required. PHP versions below 5.3.7 are not recommended for security reasons. PHP7 is recommended for X-Cart versions 4.7.6 and later for better performance."

Answer (score 0):

1)Check your xcart_dir/var/log directory

or
2)Enable development mode and debug mode
https://help.x-cart.com/index.php?title=X-Cart:Config.php#Development_mode_and_debug_mode_settings

We recommend the following settings for development:
$debug_mode = 3;
define('DEVELOPMENT_MODE', 1);

or
3)Try to open a page like this 
http://demo.x-cart.com/demo_goldplus/check_requirements.php?checkrequirements=1&auth_code=BG6GJH39

$installation_auth_code(BG6GJH39) can be found in the config.php file

or
4)Check you \xampp\apache\logs\error.log apache logs
[Where does PHP's error log reside in XAMPP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719549/where-does-phps-error-log-reside-in-xampp)

PS
Do you mean X-Cart 4.7.6 ?