# HTML not rendering on php page

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, admin

I'm making an app with complete php. I'm using a bootstrap admin template to make the code. However, when I run the application, some pages aren't rendered. Instead, when I navigate to the page, it displays a localhost error that just says "check errors". An example of this is when I navigate from the index page to the user profile page. I receive an error from the application when I try to use a link to navigate to the app's profile page. How do I fix this?

Comment: Start with `checking errors`.

Comment: Check the error log of your webserver

Comment: @NieDzejkob It doesn't have an error log. I'm using Xampp as the server for php.

Comment: @metaco57 You do have it, you just don't know about it. [Where does PHP's error log reside in XAMPP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719549/where-does-phps-error-log-reside-in-xampp)

Comment: Please review the following and edit your question appropriately:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. The error log was saying that I wasn't including a file properly. Once I fixed it, the application worked. Thank you.