# Can't Set Configuration Runtime in php.ini

Tags: php, xampp

I wanna ask about how to set the load time process when we upload large files in php.

When I have 14 datas, the program can be processed and show us the result like this : small data

When I have large datas, approximately 8000 datas, the program can not be processed and the result is : large data

I have the set the max_execution_time=-1 and max_input_time = -1, memory_limit=-1 in file (php.ini). I am using xampp version 3.2.2. But, it is not working for uploading 8000 datas and the page can not be loading and show us the problem : the page is not working; HTTP error 500, what should i do?

The code can be seen in below :

```html
[PHP]
; max_input_time
;   Default Value: -1 (Unlimited)
;   Development Value: 60 (60 seconds)
;   Production Value: 60 (60 seconds)

; output_buffering
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: 4096
;   Production Value: 4096

; register_argc_argv
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: Off
;   Production Value: Off

; register_long_arrays
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: Off
;   Production Value: Off

; request_order
;   Default Value: None
;   Development Value: "GP"
;   Production Value: "GP"

; session.bug_compat_42
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

; session.bug_compat_warn
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

; session.gc_divisor
;   Default Value: 100
;   Development Value: 1000
;   Production Value: 1000

; session.hash_bits_per_character
;   Default Value: 4
;   Development Value: 5
;   Production Value: 5

; short_open_tag
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: Off
;   Production Value: Off

; track_errors
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

; url_rewriter.tags
;   Default Value: "a=href,area=href,frame=src,form=,fieldset="
;   Development Value: "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"
;   Production Value: "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"

; variables_order
;   Default Value: "EGPCS"
;   Development Value: "GPCS"
;   Production Value: "GPCS"

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; php.ini Options  ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Name for user-defined php.ini (.htaccess) files. Default is ".user.ini"
;user_ini.filename = ".user.ini"

; To disable this feature set this option to empty value
;user_ini.filename =

; TTL for user-defined php.ini files (time-to-live) in seconds. Default is 300 seconds (5 minutes)
;user_ini.cache_ttl = 300

  
; Development Value: 4096
; Production Value: 4096
; http://php.net/output-buffering
output_buffering=4096

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Miscellaneous ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Decides whether PHP may expose the fact that it is installed on the server
; (e.g. by adding its signature to the Web server header).  It is no security
; threat in any way, but it makes it possible to determine whether you use PHP
; on your server or not.
; http://php.net/expose-php
expose_php=On

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Resource Limits ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
; http://php.net/max-execution-time
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI
max_execution_time=-1

; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data. It's a good
; idea to limit this time on productions servers in order to eliminate unexpectedly
; long running scripts.
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to -1 for the CLI SAPI
; Default Value: -1 (Unlimited)
; Development Value: 60 (60 seconds)
; Production Value: 60 (60 seconds)
; http://php.net/max-input-time
max_input_time=-1

; Maximum input variable nesting level
; http://php.net/max-input-nesting-level
;max_input_nesting_level = 64

; How many GET/POST/COOKIE input variables may be accepted
; max_input_vars = 1000

; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit=-1

error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT

; This directive controls whether or not and where PHP will output errors,
; notices and warnings too. Error output is very useful during development, but
; it could be very dangerous in production environments. Depending on the code
; which is triggering the error, sensitive information could potentially leak
; out of your application such as database usernames and passwords or worse.
; It's recommended that errors be logged on production servers rather than
; having the errors sent to STDOUT.
; Possible Values:
;   Off = Do not display any errors 
;   stderr = Display errors to STDERR (affects only CGI/CLI binaries!)   
;   On or stdout = Display errors to STDOUT
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: On
; Production Value: Off
; http://php.net/display-errors
display_errors=On

; The display of errors which occur during PHP's startup sequence are handled
; separately from display_errors. PHP's default behavior is to suppress those
; errors from clients. Turning the display of startup errors on can be useful in
; debugging configuration problems. But, it's strongly recommended that you
; leave this setting off on production servers.
; Default Value: Off
; Development Value: On
; Production Value: Off
; http://php.net/display-startup-errors
; XAMPP: Turn display_startup_errors = Off here for a full Joomla support
display_startup_errors=On

html_errors=On

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; If you wish to have an extension loaded automatically, use the following
; syntax:
;
;   extension=modulename.extension
;
; For example, on Windows:
;
;   extension=msql.dll
;
; ... or under UNIX:
;
;   extension=msql.so
;
; ... or with a path:
;
;   extension=/path/to/extension/msql.so
;
; If you only provide the name of the extension, PHP will look for it in its
; default extension directory.
;
; Windows Extensions
; Note that ODBC support is built in, so no dll is needed for it.
; Note that many DLL files are located in the extensions/ (PHP 4) ext/ (PHP 5)
; extension folders as well as the separate PECL DLL download (PHP 5).
; Be sure to appropriately set the extension_dir directive.

extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
;extension=php_mssql.dll
;extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8.dll      ; Use with Oracle 10gR2 Instant Client
;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll  ; Use with Oracle 11gR2 Instant Client

extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlite_external.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pspell.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll

; The MIBS data available in the PHP distribution must be installed. 
; See http://www.php.net/manual/en/snmp.installation.php 
;extension=php_snmp.dll

extension=php_soap.dll
extension=php_sockets.dll
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
;extension=php_sybase_ct.dll
;extension=php_tidy.dll
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
extension=php_xsl.dll

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Module Settings ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[CLI Server]
; Whether the CLI web server uses ANSI color coding in its terminal output.
cli_server.color=On

[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone=Europe/Berlin

; http://php.net/date.default-latitude
;date.default_latitude = 31.7667

; http://php.net/date.default-longitude
;date.default_longitude = 35.2333

; http://php.net/date.sunrise-zenith
;date.sunrise_zenith = 90.583333

; http://php.net/date.sunset-zenith
;date.sunset_zenith = 90.583333

[filter]
; http://php.net/filter.default
;filter.default = unsafe_raw

; http://php.net/filter.default-flags
;filter.default_flags =

[iconv]
;iconv.input_encoding = ISO-8859-1
;iconv.internal_encoding = ISO-8859-1
;iconv.output_encoding = ISO-8859-1

[intl]
;intl.default_locale =
; This directive allows you to produce PHP errors when some error
; happens within intl functions. The value is the level of the error produced.
; Default is 0, which does not produce any errors.
;intl.error_level = E_WARNING

[sqlite]
; http://php.net/sqlite.assoc-case
;sqlite.assoc_case = 0

[sqlite3]
;sqlite3.extension_dir =

[Pcre]
;PCRE library backtracking limit.
; http://php.net/pcre.backtrack-limit
;pcre.backtrack_limit=100000

;PCRE library recursion limit.
;Please note that if you set this value to a high number you may consume all
;the available process stack and eventually crash PHP (due to reaching the
;stack size limit imposed by the Operating System).
; http://php.net/pcre.recursion-limit
;pcre.recursion_limit=100000

[Pdo]
; Whether to pool ODBC connections. Can be one of "strict", "relaxed" or "off"
; http://php.net/pdo-odbc.connection-pooling
;pdo_odbc.connection_pooling=strict

;pdo_odbc.db2_instance_name

[Pdo_mysql]
; If mysqlnd is used: Number of cache slots for the internal result set cache
; http://php.net/pdo_mysql.cache_size
pdo_mysql.cache_size=2000

; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
; MySQL defaults.
; http://php.net/pdo_mysql.default-socket
pdo_mysql.default_socket="MySQL"

[Phar]
; http://php.net/phar.readonly
;phar.readonly = On

; http://php.net/phar.require-hash
;phar.require_hash = On

;phar.cache_list =

[Syslog]
; Whether or not to define the various syslog variables (e.g. $LOG_PID,
; $LOG_CRON, etc.).  Turning it off is a good idea performance-wise.  In
; runtime, you can define these variables by calling define_syslog_variables().
; http://php.net/define-syslog-variables
define_syslog_variables=Off

[SQL]
; http://php.net/sql.safe-mode
sql.safe_mode=Off

[ODBC]
; http://php.net/odbc.default-db
;odbc.default_db    =  Not yet implemented

; http://php.net/odbc.default-user
;odbc.default_user  =  Not yet implemented

; Check that a connection is still valid before reuse.
; http://php.net/odbc.check-persistent
odbc.check_persistent=On

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/odbc.max-persistent
odbc.max_persistent=-1

; Maximum number of links (persistent + non-persistent).  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/odbc.max-links
odbc.max_links=-1

; Handling of LONG fields.  Returns number of bytes to variables.  0 means
; passthru.
; http://php.net/odbc.defaultlrl
odbc.defaultlrl=4096

; Handling of binary data.  0 means passthru, 1 return as is, 2 convert to char.
; See the documentation on odbc_binmode and odbc_longreadlen for an explanation
; of odbc.defaultlrl and odbc.defaultbinmode
; http://php.net/odbc.defaultbinmode
odbc.defaultbinmode=1

;birdstep.max_links = -1

[Interbase]
; Allow or prevent persistent links.
ibase.allow_persistent=1

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
ibase.max_persistent=-1

; Maximum number of links (persistent + non-persistent).  -1 means no limit.
ibase.max_links=-1

; Default database name for ibase_connect().
;ibase.default_db =

; Default charset for ibase_connect().
;ibase.default_charset =

; Default timestamp format.
ibase.timestampformat="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

; Default date format.
ibase.dateformat="%Y-%m-%d"

; Default time format.
ibase.timeformat="%H:%M:%S"

[MySQL]
; Allow accessing, from PHP's perspective, local files with LOAD DATA statements
; http://php.net/mysql.allow_local_infile
mysql.allow_local_infile=On

; Allow or prevent persistent links.
; http://php.net/mysql.allow-persistent
mysql.allow_persistent=On

; If mysqlnd is used: Number of cache slots for the internal result set cache
; http://php.net/mysql.cache_size
mysql.cache_size=2000

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/mysql.max-persistent
mysql.max_persistent=-1

; Maximum number of links (persistent + non-persistent).  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/mysql.max-links
mysql.max_links=-1

; Default port number for mysql_connect().  If unset, mysql_connect() will use
; the $MYSQL_TCP_PORT or the mysql-tcp entry in /etc/services or the
; compile-time value defined MYSQL_PORT (in that order).  Win32 will only look
; at MYSQL_PORT.
; http://php.net/mysql.default-port
mysql.default_port=3306

; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
; MySQL defaults.
; http://php.net/mysql.default-socket
mysql.default_socket="MySQL"

; Default host for mysql_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
; http://php.net/mysql.default-host
mysql.default_host=

; Default user for mysql_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
; http://php.net/mysql.default-user
mysql.default_user=

; Default password for mysql_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
; Note that this is generally a *bad* idea to store passwords in this file.
; *Any* user with PHP access can run 'echo get_cfg_var("mysql.default_password")
; and reveal this password!  And of course, any users with read access to this
; file will be able to reveal the password as well.
; http://php.net/mysql.default-password
mysql.default_password=

; Maximum time (in seconds) for connect timeout. -1 means no limit
; http://php.net/mysql.connect-timeout
mysql.connect_timeout=3

; Trace mode. When trace_mode is active (=On), warnings for table/index scans and
; SQL-Errors will be displayed.
; http://php.net/mysql.trace-mode
mysql.trace_mode=Off

[MySQLi]

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/mysqli.max-persistent
mysqli.max_persistent=-1

; Allow accessing, from PHP's perspective, local files with LOAD DATA statements
; http://php.net/mysqli.allow_local_infile
mysqli.allow_local_infile=On

; Allow or prevent persistent links.
; http://php.net/mysqli.allow-persistent
mysqli.allow_persistent=On

; Maximum number of links.  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/mysqli.max-links
mysqli.max_links=-1

; If mysqlnd is used: Number of cache slots for the internal result set cache
; http://php.net/mysqli.cache_size
mysqli.cache_size=2000

; Default port number for mysqli_connect().  If unset, mysqli_connect() will use
; the $MYSQL_TCP_PORT or the mysql-tcp entry in /etc/services or the
; compile-time value defined MYSQL_PORT (in that order).  Win32 will only look
; at MYSQL_PORT.
; http://php.net/mysqli.default-port
mysqli.default_port=3306
mysqli.default_socket="MySQL"

; Default host for mysql_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
; http://php.net/mysqli.default-host
mysqli.default_host=

; Default user for mysql_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
; http://php.net/mysqli.default-user
mysqli.default_user=

; Default password for mysqli_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
; Note that this is generally a *bad* idea to store passwords in this file.
; *Any* user with PHP access can run 'echo get_cfg_var("mysqli.default_pw")
; and reveal this password!  And of course, any users with read access to this
; file will be able to reveal the password as well.
; http://php.net/mysqli.default-pw
mysqli.default_pw=

; Allow or prevent reconnect
mysqli.reconnect=Off

[mysqlnd]
; Enable / Disable collection of general statstics by mysqlnd which can be
; used to tune and monitor MySQL operations.
; http://php.net/mysqlnd.collect_statistics
mysqlnd.collect_statistics=On

; Enable / Disable collection of memory usage statstics by mysqlnd which can be
; used to tune and monitor MySQL operations.
; http://php.net/mysqlnd.collect_memory_statistics
mysqlnd.collect_memory_statistics=Off

; Size of a pre-allocated buffer used when sending commands to MySQL in bytes.
; http://php.net/mysqlnd.net_cmd_buffer_size
;mysqlnd.net_cmd_buffer_size = 2048

; Size of a pre-allocated buffer used for reading data sent by the server in
; bytes.
; http://php.net/mysqlnd.net_read_buffer_size
;mysqlnd.net_read_buffer_size = 32768

[PostgresSQL]
; Allow or prevent persistent links.
; http://php.net/pgsql.allow-persistent
pgsql.allow_persistent=On

; Detect broken persistent links always with pg_pconnect().
; Auto reset feature requires a little overheads.
; http://php.net/pgsql.auto-reset-persistent
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent=Off

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/pgsql.max-persistent
pgsql.max_persistent=-1

; Maximum number of links (persistent+non persistent).  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/pgsql.max-links
pgsql.max_links=-1

; Ignore PostgreSQL backends Notice message or not.
; Notice message logging require a little overheads.
; http://php.net/pgsql.ignore-notice
pgsql.ignore_notice=0

; Log PostgreSQL backends Noitce message or not.
; Unless pgsql.ignore_notice=0, module cannot log notice message.
; http://php.net/pgsql.log-notice
pgsql.log_notice=0

[Sybase-CT]
; Allow or prevent persistent links.
; http://php.net/sybct.allow-persistent
sybct.allow_persistent=On

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/sybct.max-persistent
sybct.max_persistent=-1

; Maximum number of links (persistent + non-persistent).  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/sybct.max-links
sybct.max_links=-1

; Minimum server message severity to display.
; http://php.net/sybct.min-server-severity
sybct.min_server_severity=10

; Minimum client message severity to display.
; http://php.net/sybct.min-client-severity
sybct.min_client_severity=10

; Set per-context timeout
; http://php.net/sybct.timeout
;sybct.timeout=

;sybct.packet_size

; The maximum time in seconds to wait for a connection attempt to succeed before returning failure.
; Default: one minute
;sybct.login_timeout=

; The name of the host you claim to be connecting from, for display by sp_who.
; Default: none
;sybct.hostname=

; Allows you to define how often deadlocks are to be retried. -1 means "forever".
; Default: 0
;sybct.deadlock_retry_count=

[bcmath]
; Number of decimal digits for all bcmath functions.
; http://php.net/bcmath.scale
bcmath.scale=0

[browscap]
; http://php.net/browscap
browscap="C:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini"

[Session]
; Handler used to store/retrieve data.
; http://php.net/session.save-handler
session.save_handler=files

session.save_path="C:\xampp\tmp"

; Whether to use cookies.
; http://php.net/session.use-cookies
session.use_cookies=1

; http://php.net/session.cookie-secure
;session.cookie_secure =

; This option forces PHP to fetch and use a cookie for storing and maintaining
; the session id. We encourage this operation as it's very helpful in combatting
; session hijacking when not specifying and managing your own session id. It is
; not the end all be all of session hijacking defense, but it's a good start.
; http://php.net/session.use-only-cookies
session.use_only_cookies=0

; Name of the session (used as cookie name).
; http://php.net/session.name
session.name=PHPSESSID

; Initialize session on request startup.
; http://php.net/session.auto-start
session.auto_start=0

; Lifetime in seconds of cookie or, if 0, until browser is restarted.
; http://php.net/session.cookie-lifetime
session.cookie_lifetime=0

; The path for which the cookie is valid.
; http://php.net/session.cookie-path
session.cookie_path=/

; The domain for which the cookie is valid.
; http://php.net/session.cookie-domain
session.cookie_domain=

; Whether or not to add the httpOnly flag to the cookie, which makes it inaccessible to browser scripting languages such as JavaScript.
; http://php.net/session.cookie-httponly
session.cookie_httponly=

; Handler used to serialize data.  php is the standard serializer of PHP.
; http://php.net/session.serialize-handler
session.serialize_handler=php

; Defines the probability that the 'garbage collection' process is started
; on every session initialization. The probability is calculated by using
; gc_probability/gc_divisor. Where session.gc_probability is the numerator
; and gc_divisor is the denominator in the equation. Setting this value to 1
; when the session.gc_divisor value is 100 will give you approximately a 1% chance
; the gc will run on any give request.
; Default Value: 1
; Development Value: 1
; Production Value: 1
; http://php.net/session.gc-probability
session.gc_probability=1

; Defines the probability that the 'garbage collection' process is started on every
; session initialization. The probability is calculated by using the following equation:
; gc_probability/gc_divisor. Where session.gc_probability is the numerator and
; session.gc_divisor is the denominator in the equation. Setting this value to 1
; when the session.gc_divisor value is 100 will give you approximately a 1% chance
; the gc will run on any give request. Increasing this value to 1000 will give you
; a 0.1% chance the gc will run on any give request. For high volume production servers,
; this is a more efficient approach.
; Default Value: 100
; Development Value: 1000
; Production Value: 1000
; http://php.net/session.gc-divisor
session.gc_divisor=1000

; After this number of seconds, stored data will be seen as 'garbage' and
; cleaned up by the garbage collection process.
; http://php.net/session.gc-maxlifetime
session.gc_maxlifetime=1440

; used and debugging errors caused by this can be difficult to track down.
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: On
; Production Value: Off
; http://php.net/session.bug-compat-42
session.bug_compat_42=On

; This setting controls whether or not you are warned by PHP when initializing a
; session value into the global space. session.bug_compat_42 must be enabled before
; these warnings can be issued by PHP. See the directive above for more information.
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: On
; Production Value: Off
; http://php.net/session.bug-compat-warn
session.bug_compat_warn=On

; Check HTTP Referer to invalidate externally stored URLs containing ids.
; HTTP_REFERER has to contain this substring for the session to be
; considered as valid.
; http://php.net/session.referer-check
session.referer_check=

; How many bytes to read from the file.
; http://php.net/session.entropy-length
session.entropy_length=0

; Specified here to create the session id.
; http://php.net/session.entropy-file
; Defaults to /dev/urandom
; On systems that don't have /dev/urandom but do have /dev/arandom, this will default to /dev/arandom
; If neither are found at compile time, the default is no entropy file.
; On windows, setting the entropy_length setting will activate the
; Windows random source (using the CryptoAPI)
;session.entropy_file = /dev/urandom
session.entropy_file=

; http://php.net/session.entropy-length
;session.entropy_length = 16

; Set to {nocache,private,public,} to determine HTTP caching aspects
; or leave this empty to avoid sending anti-caching headers.
; http://php.net/session.cache-limiter
session.cache_limiter=nocache

; Document expires after n minutes.
; http://php.net/session.cache-expire
session.cache_expire=180

; Enable upload progress tracking in $_SESSION
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: On
; Production Value: On
; http://php.net/session.upload-progress.enabled
;session.upload_progress.enabled = On

; Cleanup the progress information as soon as all POST data has been read
; (i.e. upload completed).
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: On
; Production Value: On
; http://php.net/session.upload-progress.cleanup
;session.upload_progress.cleanup = On

; A prefix used for the upload progress key in $_SESSION
; Default Value: "upload_progress_"
; Development Value: "upload_progress_"
; Production Value: "upload_progress_"
; http://php.net/session.upload-progress.prefix
;session.upload_progress.prefix = "upload_progress_"

; The index name (concatenated with the prefix) in $_SESSION
; containing the upload progress information
; Default Value: "PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS"
; Development Value: "PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS"
; Production Value: "PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS"
; http://php.net/session.upload-progress.name
;session.upload_progress.name = "PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS"

; How frequently the upload progress should be updated.
; Given either in percentages (per-file), or in bytes
; Default Value: "1%"
; Development Value: "1%"
; Production Value: "1%"
; http://php.net/session.upload-progress.freq
;session.upload_progress.freq =  "1%"

; The minimum delay between updates, in seconds
; Default Value: 1
; Development Value: 1
; Production Value: 1
; http://php.net/session.upload-progress.min-freq
;session.upload_progress.min_freq = "1"
```

The result for 14 datas [success process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYcIL.jpg)

The result for 8000 datas [failed process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNP7i.jpg)

Comment: First, you have to check your Apache logs to see what is the error. Maybe a memory limit.

Comment: where should i see that?

Comment: This anwser should helps you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719549/where-does-phps-error-log-reside-in-xampp

Comment: it's look like 
[Tue Feb 06 18:49:26.465389 2018] [core:warn] [pid 9852:tid 376] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Tue Feb 06 18:49:27.429289 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9852:tid 376] AH00455: Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.15 configured -- resuming normal operations

Comment: Only that ? No previous errors ?

Comment: yes.. there's no error message..what should i do?