# CKFinder3 Invalid Request Error

Tags: php, ckfinder

Hellow everyone!
I want to use the CKFinder 3 PHP version.

I download the CKFinder zip file from official website.

Then i install XAMPP 7.2.4 to deploy the CKFinder.
[image]

I start the Apache Web Server at port 80.

Then i copy the CKFinder files to /XAMPP/htdocs/
[image]

In order to ensure the PHP environment is correct，I follow the official website to create a test.php which include these code:
[image]
[image]

And i also follow the offecial website to update `config.php` file:

```
$config['authentication'] = function () {
return true;
};
```

Now everything is ok, But when I try to access the ckfinder.html at `http://localhost/ckfinder/ckfinder.html`, some error occured.
[image]

i can see error log :

```
[04-May-2018 10:29:57 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught CKSource\CKFinder\Exception\InvalidConfigException:
 The temporary folder is not writable for CKFinder in 
 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ckfinder/core/connector/php/vendor/cksource/ckfinder/src/CKSource/CKFinder/Config.php:331
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test.php file seems to be outdated, Make sure that your system meets the following requirements:

- PHP 5.6+
  Note: PHP 7.0+ is required for the Dropbox backend.
- GD extension enabled (default on most installations) for thumbnail support and any image operations.
- FileInfo extension enabled. Note: By default disabled on XAMPP, read Quick Start for more information.
- JSON MIME type supported. Note: By default disabled on IIS Express, read Quick Start for more information.

Check error log on the server, it should have more details information about the source of the issue.

Comment: Hi, I update my question , see my php version is 7.0+  and test.php runs correctlly

Comment: Check error logs. There is a chance that you made a typo in the config file. For example forgot to close a string etc. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719549/where-does-phps-error-log-reside-in-xampp

Comment: Thx, I found the error log :  The temporary folder is not writable for CKFinder , I print the 'tempDirectory' , it is  `/var/folders/dc/5xk_d2bn02v05bsybw8q483c0000gn/T`  . what is this ?

Comment: You can configure it with https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckfinder/ckfinder3-php/configuration.html#configuration_options_tempDirectory
CKFinder needs to have access to a safe tmp directory for file verification before they are moved to the destination folder. So after you configure the right tmp folder and make it writable it should start working.