# Xampp accepts Ajax requests

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, rest

I am trying to implement an API on my system, but every time of the problem, I do locally ... via server on hosting, handle calmly.

I have a question that is as follows, does XAMPP accept Ajax? I searched the internet and found nothing about it.

Comment: **Welcome to Stack Overflow**, please try to be more specific and try to explain your issue in more details and show us what did you have done in order to solve it. Try, also, to regard some code.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is just a term for making an HTTP request from client-side JavaScript without leaving the current webpage.

As far as the HTTP server is concerned, there is no real difference between an HTTP request initiated using Ajax and one initiated using any other method.

The only proviso is that browsers implement a [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) which can lead to the *browser* forbidding JavaScript from reading the response (or, in the case of preflighted requests, making the request in the first place) unless [the server adds headers granting explicit permission](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068).

Apache HTTPD (the HTTP server distributed with XAMPP) is quite capable of being configured to add these headers, but it is more common to add them using a server-side programming language (such as PHP).

Answer (score 0):

It should work, I've done it anyway. You may have to check the error log to find out why its failing. First off what does your browser log for code or connection issues, this will detail if its a CORS issue (F12 in chrome for me)? If the issue isn't there then you may have to check the Xampp log: \xampp\apache\logs\error.log for that application.

Also can be done this way:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38347316/10980320

Answer (score -1):

Yes, XAMPP accepts AJAX requests! All requests, no matter whether they're through AJAX or just directly visiting the page through a browser, request and receive the data in a specific way. As far as I know, there isn't really a way to not support one type of request or another, although they can probably be blocked.

Feel free to correct me.