# Blank page on PHP (7.3.9) using Xampp 3.2.4

Tags: php, xampp, tcpdf

So I am using xampp as my server hosting, and haven't got a problem in years. But I found something strange happening.

I have this code:

```
require "init.php";
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

$pdf = new TCPDF("P", "mm", 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);

var_dump($pdf);
```

If I execute this code. My page is fully blank? And sometimes it isn't. Like so:

[image]

But when I execute my page in a command line, like so:

```
c:\xampp\php\php.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\websites\Traject-Parket\index.php
```

I get the var_dump I wrote.

[image]

So I have no errors whats so ever? How come my page is blank and sometimes isn't? Because in this project nothing seems to work but in other projects it does.

Comment: Do you have any errors in your logs when you are running your PHP from your browser ?

Comment: Check if the local php configuration is correct, maybe installing a newer version off that program maybe that helps

Comment: Also check `phpinfo()` (through the web server) and then `php -v` from the command line to make sure they are using the same PHP version.

Comment: @Nicolas Is their a tool for that?

Comment: @RaymondNijland It is, I have the latest versions

Comment: @MagnusEriksson It's the same

Comment: @Mark_ Usually it's in a file somewhere. a quick google search got me [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719549/where-does-phps-error-log-reside-in-xampp)

Comment: @Nicolas Okay I found something interesting, I get this: [Fri Dec 20 15:09:59.038835 2019] [php7:error] [pid 10640:tid 1892] [client ::1:55357] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\websites\\Traject-Parket\\vendor\\tecnickcom\\tcpdf\\tcpdf.php on line 8147

Comment: It looks like xampp is not getting enough RAM. could you check in your php.ini and increase the `memory_limit ` value

Comment: check the memory limits in both your php.ini and your php-cli.ini

Comment: This is working in cli because xampp and Cli does not have the same php.ini file.

Comment: kind of what i just said :-P

Comment: I increased the memory limit, it was on default "128M" and I set it to like 518M and nothing changed, So I set even higher but still same error log? How much should I set it? And I don't have a php-cli.ini file.

Comment: Okay update, I added this code: ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');  to the top of my page and it works! But maybe this isn't the cleanest way is it? And I want this to be hosted on a different server later or soon, will that cause problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blank pages (or WSOD, white screen of death) is when your script fails. 
You don;'t have display_errors turned on, so at the top of your script, you can say:

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(-1);
```

And that will allow you to see the error.

However, it isn't the best way. Error logging directly to the screen not onl;y distorts your page, but can ruin `header()` calls, as the HTTP body has already started outputting and thus no more HTTP headers can come out.

For the best error logging experience, set `error_reporting` to -1, turn `display_errors` off, and set a custom `error_log`. Then in the terminal, type `tail -f /path/to/error_log`. Your notices, warnings and errors will now scroll past in real time, without distorting your web page's display.

Comment: This is a good answer, however i'm not sur if it answer OP's question. if you look at [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59426313/blank-page-on-php-7-3-9-using-xampp-3-2-4?noredirect=1#comment105039294_59426313) it looks like a memory issue rather than an error logging one.

Comment: Of course it does. He's asking about a white screen! Now he has found his error, but he hasn't updated his question, so it remains, why is this page blank?

Comment: Youre right! This fixed my problem on finding my error. Thanks! And ofcourse the rest of you guys

Comment: like i say, learn to tail the log rather than use display_errors though, you'll thank yourself!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this library, but `var_dump` shows that unprotected data from PHP 5.6.0.

Maybe the problem comes from there?

Look at the `__debugInfo()` method

And give us the exit.