# Why is XAMPP not finding the files

Tags: php, xampp

So, I have been trying to use the XAMPP server as part of my school project, but I am getting an internal server error when I try to require a particular php file from another directory, here is what I mean:

I have this directory heirarchy:

[image: directory_structure]

and in my `about.php` file I am trying to require the `about.view.php` but I get an internal server error when I do that. Here is my `about.php` content:

[image: about.php page]

Why am I getting this error? and I tried every possible thing I can think of. Please, help me out.

Comment: Please don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)!

Comment: `about.php` is in a folder `controllers`. The `views` folder is on the same level as `controllers`, so you'd need to move to the parent directory (`../`) first

Comment: @brombeer I have tried that, but I get this error `localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500`

Comment: Check the PHP or Apache error log files then, to try and see exactly what caused the 500

Comment: @ADyson How Can I do that? Where do I find the log files?

Comment: That depends on your configuration. php.ini should  have the PHP error log file configuration specified. Off the top of my head for Apache I forget how it's controlled, but you should be able to easily google it.

Comment: [Where does PHP's error log reside in XAMPP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719549/where-does-phps-error-log-reside-in-xampp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How to require file from another folder?

Your `about.php` file is located in the `controllers` folder. You want to include the `views/about.view.php` file according to your code. That means starting from `about.php`, you want to include the `controller/views/about.view.php` file. This is incorrect because your views folder is not inside the `controllers` folder. It is located outside of it.

**The correct approach is to go up one level by using `../`.** This means starting from your interhub folder, the request should be interpreted as `../views/about.view.php`. So, it starts from the `controllers` folder, then goes back one level to the `interhub` folder with `../`, and then goes into the `views` folder with `/views`. After these steps, it will find the `about.view.php` file and your code will run correctly.

```php
require_once "../views/about.view.php";
```

[More information - file path](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)

###### Extra - How to can view errors?

Okay, this file reference is fixed, check! If you receive further 500 error codes, it's definitely not because of this, but rather due to an error in your PHP code. You can output the errors to the screen or view them in the Apache error.log file.

```php
// Show error message instead of "Error 500" blank page.
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

> **Warning!** Use it exclusively for home development purposes!
> In live code, this poses a security vulnerability!